# Getting latitude and longitude updates based off of change in distance for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I know with the Android and the Location API's it's possible to receive periodic updates of latitude and longitude through an interval of time using the "setInterval" method and other methods on the "LocationRequest" class, but what I'm wondering is, what would be a good way to get latitude and longitude updates via GPS based off of a change in distance compared to the previous location without having it on all the time and not wasting battery (preferably a solution that is energy efficient).

For example, say I start at one place and then 2 minutes later I'm 5km from the distance that I originally started at. At this point the GPS would detect the change in location and update the latitude and longitude on the device.

If anyone could provide some insight or code samples on how to do this, that'd be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can based your position attribute update on how far you are from the previous location, but you can't based GPS frequency update on that, simply because you need a location request to find out that you are far enough.

If you want an energy efficient solution, you can reduce the rate at which new update appear. You can also reduce the window duration in which you listen for position (position may be less accurate).

A lot of information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), specially in `Adjusting the model to save battery and data exchange` and `Deciding when to start listening for updates` chapters

Comment: I've read over the section you recommended, but I was wondering what are your suggestions for providing location updates when the app isn't currently active and location updates would be delivered via a receiver and a service and a user would be notified of a change in location through something like a push notification. For example, isn't using their phone, but their position has changed 5km compared to their previous position a few minutes ago, what would be your suggestions for tracking these latitude and longitude changes?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html); it's quite close from what you are trying to achieve. They want to be notified when they get close to a point of interest, and you want to be notified when you get away from it...

Comment: Thanks for providing the suggestion this really helped in leading me to find my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can get the location change if you specify the distance you want to get updates in the [requestLocationUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) parameter.

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

Here is example:

```
LocationManager yourLoc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
yourLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 2, onLocationChange);
```

Here you will receive location changes after every 2 meters you have travelled, irrespective of the time you spent at a particular location.

Hope that answers your question!!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I just read about this in the API documentation right before reading your answer